Courant and John state that theorems proven for functions of two variables can be easily extended to functions of $n$ variables. Why is this so?
I’m paraphrasing a bit in the title, so here’s the full statement:

As a rule, a theorem that can be proved for functions of two (emphasis theirs) variables may be extended easily to functions of more than two variables without any essential change in the proof.

Source: Courant, Richard, and Fritz John. Introduction to Calculus and Analysis II/1. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012, p. 1.

My question is: why is this true? I don't know much about mathematics at this point, but what property of functions, or perhaps mathematics in general, makes this possible? Surely, some things break down, right? Am I just interpreting the statement too literally?

Induction is one way to think about it. But in general, suppose that something holds for all functions of upto 47 variables. Why 47? What's so special about that? Two isn't really very different, if you think about it.

My advice: do not read too much into this informal chitchat. These things make much more sense to the authors than they make to the reader.

Lots of theorems in analysis involving multiple variable functions end up depending on just things like vector addition and the triangle inequality (in $n$-dimensions), and these have the same properties regardless of the dimension.
So, for example, a proof written with $\|\cdot \|$ meaning the $\mathbb R^2$-norm would still valid if it represented the $\mathbb R^5$-norm.
(Although the quantity $n$ might pop into some equations when estimating quantities, but this usually doesn't make a qualitative difference.)
I think the reason they are emphasizing two is that they are excluding one. And this is because 1-dimensional real numbers have something that doesn't extend to higher dimensions: an ordering, one that is compatible with algebraic manipulations. So there are many theorems about $\mathbb R^1$ that don't extend to general $\mathbb R^n$, as their proofs rely on using "less than".

(+1) especially for your last paragraph.

Thank you, this answer helped!
